# How do I make this object immutable

Tags: javascript, object, deep-copy

I am working with this code below

```
const recipes = {
  recipe1: {
    title: "pancake",
    serving: 4,
    ingredients: ["flour", "egg", "milk", "vanilla", "baking Powder"],
  },
  recipe2: {
    title: "eggSalad",
    serving: 2,
    ingredients: ["egg", "mayo", "lettuce", "cucumber", "tomato"],
  },
  recipe3: {
    title: "omelette",
    serving: 4,
    ingredients: ["egg", "mushroom", "pepper", "salt", "tomato"],
  }
};

const arr1 = Object.assign({}, {...recipes})

Object.values(arr1).forEach(e => {
  console.log(e.title)
  console.log(e.serving)
  console.log(e.ingredients)

  e.title = "this has been mutated"
})

console.log(recipes)
```

I want to log each recipe, which I have done successfully. HOWEVER, I also don't want to mutate the object. I thought by using the Object.assign along with the `...` / spread operator, it would sever ties with the original `recipes` object. But on the last console log, the original object is in fact mutated and logs each recipe title with `'this has been mutated'`

I am very confused why this is happening, and furthermore, cannot find a solution in which I can copy the orginal array without mutating it.

I am sure I am doing something rather silly, but I want to maintain good practice of keeping things immutable, and I cannot get this to work!

Can anyone help, or even better, educate me where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `recipe1`...`recipe3` are objects too, and you only assign this 3 parents, not their properties, you have to repeat the assign for each one : `Object.assign(arr1.recipe1, recipes.recipe1  )`...

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a "deep copy" of your nested objects, you have to create copies for every non-primitive value (plain object or array object) within.

Otherwise, the objects within will still be same objects in the original (even though you created a copy of their "container object").

In the case of your example data, you can do it using recursive spread syntax like in the example below where `copy` is created:

```js
const recipes = {
  recipe1: {
    title: "pancake",
    serving: 4,
    ingredients: ["flour", "egg", "milk", "vanilla", "baking Powder"],
  },
  recipe2: {
    title: "eggSalad",
    serving: 2,
    ingredients: ["egg", "mayo", "lettuce", "cucumber", "tomato"],
  },
  recipe3: {
    title: "omelette",
    serving: 4,
    ingredients: ["egg", "mushroom", "pepper", "salt", "tomato"],
  }
};

const copy = Object.fromEntries([...Object.entries(recipes)].map(([name, recipe]) => [name, {
  ...recipe,
  ingredients: [...recipe.ingredients],
}]));

Object.values(copy).forEach(recipe => {
  console.log(recipe);
  recipe.title = "this has been mutated";
})

console.log(recipes);
```

In the case of data that can be directly serialized as JSON without a type coercion (like your example), you can also simply use:

```js
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(recipes));
```